# Typescript class not accepting argument type

Tags: javascript, angular, class, typescript

I'm creating new classes in Angular for data model.

I have created classes in new file and initialize them ins constructor

```
export class CreditPoliciesDetails { 
    private _fileName : string ="" ;
    private _fileDate : string ="" ;
    private _fileSize : string ="" ;
    private _path : string=""; 
    private _extention: string="";
    constructor() {
        this._fileDate="fileDate";
        this._fileName="fileName";
        this._fileSize="fileSize";
        this._path="path";
        this._extention="extension";
    }
}  

export class CreditPolicies {
    private _document : CreditPoliciesDetails[];
    private _directory: string
    constructor (details: CreditPoliciesDetails[]) {
        this._document = details;
        this._directory="";
    }
    get category() {
        return this._document
    }
    public details (detail) {
        console.log(detail)

        this._document= detail;
    }
}
```

Then in my component **ts file** I declare new `CreditPoliciesDetails` array then pass it to `files` which is an array of type of `CreditPolicies`

```
  details :CreditPoliciesDetails[] = new Array <CreditPoliciesDetails>(); 

  files : CreditPolicies[] = new Array <CreditPolicies>(this.details);
```

In VS code I get a warning When I hover the argument of  `new Array <CreditPolicies>(this.details);` `Argument of type 'CreditPoliciesDetails[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreditPolicies'.
  Property '_document' is missing in type 'CreditPoliciesDetails[]'.`

And when I console.log `files` and `details` I get empty array.

I'm expecting this format

```
[  
   {  
      "directory":"string",
      "document":[{  
         "extension":"string",
         "lastModifiedDate":"string",
         "name":"string",
         "path":"string",
         "size":"0"
      }]
   }
]
```

Comment: `details` is empty array in your case. You're providing empty array as `new Array` argument, while it's expected to be a number - and will result in empty `files` array too. I'd suggest to check how arrays work in JS, because they work in TS exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the constructor, not to cast the CreditPoliciesDetails array into CreditPolicies array

```
details :CreditPoliciesDetails[] = new Array <CreditPoliciesDetails>(); 

//files : CreditPolicies[] = new Array <CreditPolicies>(this.details);

files : CreditPolicies = new CreditPolicies(this.details);
```

Comment: Files should be an array like in the expected format.
How can I call the constructor for details and files and declaring them as arrays in the same time ?

Comment: what u can do is declare the array first, then initialize it 1 by 1 in an loop or so by calling the constructor

Comment: i think u r confused in structure some where, What i understand from the code is u have 1 **file**(CreditPolicy) can have multiple **details(CreditPolicyDetails)**. if its true then its OK. means u have `details :CreditPoliciesDetails[] = new Array <CreditPoliciesDetails>();` contains the details of 1 FILE

Comment: other situation is 1 detail have 1 file. means `details :CreditPoliciesDetails[] = new Array <CreditPoliciesDetails>();` having 5 details and we want 5 **files (CreditPolicy)**

then this is something else

Comment: Files is an Array of `CreditPolicies` and every `_document` could have n detail. for example : we have many directories , and every directory contain many files..

Answer (score 0):

(this.details); Argument of type 'CreditPoliciesDetails[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreditPolicies'.

It simply says, that you have in the

```
this.details
```

an arrray of the type CreditPoliciesDetails, that you are trying to pass to the constructor.
Array used as a constructor in this case, expects arguments of type CreditPolicies. You are passing an array of CreditPoliciesDetails.

Also, I recomend using the following syntax for the previous code.

```
export class CreditPoliciesDetails { 
    constructor(
        private _fileDate="fileDate",
        private _fileName="fileName",
        private fileSize="fileSize";.....

) {}
}
```

It spares time and makes the code more eligible.

Comment: I havn't understand this part **Array used as constructor expects single values as parametres.**

Comment: Array used as a constructor in this case, expects arguments of type CreditPolicies. You are passing an array of CreditPoliciesDetails.